# Block double byte chars in a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, passwordbox

I am working on a WPF .net 3.5 application.

I need to create my own Passwordbox, because of security issues with the built in one.
the new PasswordwordBox is based on a regular TextBox.

Everything is working fine, only that in the WPF Passwordbox double bytes characters are blocked, and I want to add this behavior also to my new PasswordBox.

How can I do that?

Comment: What are double byte chars, and why would you block them? And why would a `TextBox` based password box be more secure than the built in one?

Comment: a lot of questions :) In chinese you need 2 bytes in order to represent one character, so when you press on a key in the keyborad, a little window will open up with number of characters to choose (that means that if you press on 'G' for example it could mean more than one char). this is not acceptable for a passwordbox because then someone can see what is the key you chose.

Comment: In that case you should block IMEs, and not characters with higher code-points. There are plenty of characters with code-points higher than 255 that are entered with normal keys. BTW since .net uses UTF-16 for everything(16 bit `char`s), every character needs at least 2 bytes(and a few rare ones need 4). So the multi-byte character classification isn't really useful anymore.

Comment: The problem with the regular PasswordBox is for example, the characters are not really hidden and if someone will runfor example snoop - you will see the characters and steal the password....

Comment: Is there a wat to block IMEs in a WPF TextBox?

Comment: Quick google turns up [`InputMethod.SetIsInputMethodEnabled(myTextBox, false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputmethod.setisinputmethodenabled.aspx)

Comment: I just figured that out :) thanks! add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you actually want to prevent IMEs from displaying characters you should disable the IME for your password box instead of trying to block characters with high code-points.

To disable the IME for a certain WPF textbox use: [`InputMethod.SetIsInputMethodEnabled(myTextBox, false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputmethod.setisinputmethodenabled.aspx).